# Comparing two arrays and put result in third array in php

Tags: php, arrays

**Schedule**

```
[
    {"Monday":"11:30"},
    {"Monday":"12:00"},
    {"Monday":"23:00"},
    {"Tuesday":"11:30"},
    {"Tuesday":"12:00"},
    {"Tuesday":"23:00"}
]
```

**Booked Slots**

```
[
    {"Monday":"11:30"},
    {"Tuesday":"23:00"}
]
```

The third Array should be of (**available slots**)

```
[
    {"Monday":"12:00"},
    {"Monday":"23:00"},
    {"Tuesday":"11:30"},
    {"Tuesday":"12:00"}
]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

use array_diff

```
print_r(array_diff(['{"Monday":"11:30"}','{"Monday":"12:00"}','{"Monday":"23:00"}','{"Tuesday":"11:30"}','{"Tuesday":"12:00"}','{"Tuesday":"23:00"}'], ['{"Monday":"11:30"}','{"Tuesday":"23:00"}']));
```

Comment: The error comes up: array_diff(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array

The difference between your array and mine is that mine doesn't have string params they are enclosed in curly braces without quotes around them ... how to get over this problem.

Comment: Yes because {} is used to enclose block or function in PHP. How did you build this array ?

Comment: array_push($doctor_timings, array($day_id => $time_id));

                                   $doctorTimings = json_encode($doctor_timings);

and to view that array I have to json_encode it otherwise it gives me error

Comment: Ok, remove json_endcode. And make like this https://gist.github.com/zeppi/03ac1bcd3fa2fb5c5adaf7d8a9882645

Comment: Your answer is correct.. I think there is a problem in my code when I try to use array_push function.
You can check the code snippet in the following link..see if you can find the problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62086230/how-to-convert-array-to-a-json-object

Comment: If you do print_r($doctor_timings) yous see array(array('day' => 'hour'), ...) and is Schedule info?

Comment: In php not exist json object. "json object" is a String and you can convert this String in array with json_decode("..", true) or array to string with json_encode(array).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214909/discussion-between-demon37-and-zeppi).

Comment: Sorry, another day. now I am a little busy