# How to convert array to a json object?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am trying to push values in an array and it comes like

```
[{"Monday":"11:30"},{"Monday":"12:00"},{"Monday":"23:00"},{"Tuesday":"11:30"},{"Tuesday":"12:00"},{"Tuesday":"23:00"}]
```

But I want it to be an object like

```
{

"Monday" : [ "11:30", "12:00", "23:00"]

"Tuesday" : ["11:30","12:00","23:00"]

}
```

Here is my code snippet

```php
$timings = DoctorTimings::where('doctor_id', '=', $input['doctor_id'])->get();
$doctor_timings = [];

foreach($timings as $timing) {
    $day_id = $timing->day_id;
    $time_slot_id = $timing->time_slot_id;
    $day_id =  Days::where('id', '=', $day_id)->first()->day;
    $time_id = DB::table('time_slot')->where('id', '=', $time_slot_id)->select('time')->first()->time;  
    array_push($doctor_timings, array($day_id => $time_id));
}

$doctorTimings = json_encode($doctor_timings);

echo $doctorTimings;
```

Comment: Did you intentionally skip `"Monday":"23:00"`?

Comment: sorry, It was a mistake... I correct it.

Comment: Instead of `json_encode($doctor_timings);` try `collect($doctor_timings)->toJson()`

Comment: collect($doctor_timings)->toJson() is same as json_encode($doctor_timings) ... just another way to converting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `mapToGroups` to get in the requested format. But i don't know your table structure so i got these;

```
[{"Monday":"11:30"},{"Monday":"12:00"},{"Monday":"23:00"},{"Tuesday":"11:30"},{"Tuesday":"12:00"},{"Tuesday":"23:00"}]
```

put into the collection (assuming your eloquent collection returns like that)

```
$timings = collect([
        ["Monday" => "11:30"],
        ["Monday" => "12:00"],
        ["Monday" => "23:00"],
        ["Tuesday" => "11:30"],
        ["Tuesday" => "12:00"],
        ["Tuesday" => "23:00"]
    ]);

    return $timings->mapToGroups(function ($item) {
        $day = array_key_first($item);

        return [$day => $item[$day]];
    });
```

which prints these;

```
{
  "Monday": [
    "11:30",
    "12:00",
    "23:00"
  ],
  "Tuesday": [
    "11:30",
    "12:00",
    "23:00"
  ]
}
```

Edit: (the same array you posted in online used here + same function i used for solution)

```
$days = ["Monday", "Monday"];
$time = ["11:30", "12:30"];
$doctor_timings = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($days); $i++) {
    $day_id = $days[$i];
    $time_id = $time[$i];
    array_push($doctor_timings, [$day_id => $time_id]);
}

return collect($doctor_timings)->mapToGroups(function ($item) {
    $day = array_key_first($item);

    return [$day => $item[$day]];
});
```

which prints

```
{"Monday":["11:30","12:30"]}
```

Comment: `$doctor_timings=[];
$day_id =  Monday  ;
$time_id = 11:30  ;
array_push($doctor_timings, array($day_id => $time_id)) ;
result = [ { "Monday" : "11:30" } ]`.... Instead of returning an array like ["Monday" => "11:30"] it gives me the above result

Comment: @Demon37 i don't get what do you mean ?

Comment: I didn't work for me. I am obtaining $day and $time from 2 different tables based on user_id and then pushing it into an empty array. There is a difference between your and mine array structure e.g. my ```$day_id = Monday;  $time_id=11:30; array_push($doctor_timings, $day_id => $time_id);``` gives me this [ { " Monday " : " 11:30 " } ] thing not this [ ["Monday"=>"11:30"] ]

Comment: Can you please elaborate here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/322fcb58f2d0698b27c76efcf06ea209fbb6dcc2

Comment: @Demon37 i edited and used your function + with my "same" solution

Comment: You have to paste the url here... Your edited code will have a new url

Comment: I cann't see it in my url...kindly save your code and share with me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215014/discussion-between-demon37-and-ersoy).